# jQuery $(this).closest("form").submit(); not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone please tell me why my submit is not being executed? The log tells me: "Validation passed, will submit form", but is not submitting?

```
$(function(){
    $("#ajax-payment-form input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize data, make AJAX call
        var str = $("#ajax-payment-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: templateDir+"/payment_form/payment_process.php",
            data: str,
            context: this
        }).done(function(msg) {
            // If a response is received from your server
            if(msg == 'OK') {
                console.log('Validation passed, will submit form');
                $(this).closest("form").submit();
            } else {
                 console.log(msg);
            }

        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('AJAX error');
        });
    });                                                         
});
```

Thanks for your time

thar

Comment: The $(this) in your done function is referring to the promise object more than likely. You would have to bind the function to the correct instance before using `. Closest() `

Comment: @Jhecht OP is using the `context` property.

Comment: Unsure but can you not just do `$('#ajax-payment-form').submit()`? It's not like your event is being bound to inputs in different forms

Comment: Is the submit button in the form? Also, is there a specific reason why you use `$("#ajax-payment-form")` first, and want to use `closest` later?

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` show? As @GolezTrol mentions, the target form seems to have an ID, why don't you use it?

Comment: @vohuman im not sure then. By the time I can fiddle with this it'll probably be answered by someone.

Comment: put your html code, i assume there are two forms...

Comment: @luchop there is only one form, I'am sure about that

Comment: according your code, you submit the form, when form is submitted you submit the form again. it doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @Vohuman consol.log(this) is returning the submit button

Comment: It seems the `e.preventDefault();` of the `click` event also prevents the submission of the form. Try with calling the native `submit` method => `$("#ajax-payment-form").get(0).submit()`

Comment: @Vohuman Yes i think so! no different by submitting like this :/

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
$(function(){
$("#ajax-payment-form input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize data, make AJAX call
    var str = $("#ajax-payment-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: templateDir+"/payment_form/payment_process.php",
        data: str,
        context: this
    }).done(function(msg) {
        // If a response is received from your server
        if(msg == 'OK') {
            console.log('Validation passed, will submit form');
            $this.closest("form").submit();
   //....
```

Comment: No different, still not submitting the form :/

Comment: @thar Do you listen to `submit` event somewhere else? If you are unsure, listen to `submit` event and call the [`isDefaultPrevented()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isdefaultprevented/) method of the event object.

Answer (score 0):

or shorter code: (Notice de submit event)

```
$(function(){
  $("#ajax-payment-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post(
        url: templateDir+"/payment_form/payment_process.php",
        $form.serialize(),
        function(){
            if(msg == 'OK') {
                console.log('Validation passed, will submit form');
                $form.closest("form").submit();
            } else {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        },
        'json'
    ).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
     });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: After trying this, I can tell that this will execute the submit, even if the else statement is being executed